# jqgrid - Disable Header Check box (multiselect = true) if all rows are disable

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Using jqgrid with `multiSelect="true"` option. I am disabling rows and prevent its selection based on some flag status as mentioned below

Disable row(s) based on `IS_FLAGGEd = 1`

```
//disable row which are flagged
        rowattr: function (item) {
                if (parseInt(item.IS_FLAGGED) == 1) {
                    return {"class": "ui-state-disabled ui-jqgrid-disablePointerEvents"};
                }
        },

        //prevent selection of disabled rows
        beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
            if ($(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").hasClass("ui-state-disabled")) {
                return false;   // not allow select the row
            }
            return true;    // allow select the row
        }
```

To disable header checkbox, implemented below code, but it disables the header check box even if one row is disabled.

```
//disable header checkbox only if all rows are disabled        
        loadComplete: function() {
            var grid = $("#grid");
            var ids = grid.jqGrid('getDataIDs');
            for(var i=0;i < ids.length;i++){
                var rowId = ids[i];
                var rowData = jQuery('#grid').jqGrid ('getRowData', rowId);
                console.log(rowData.SUBMIT_TO_ACC);
                 if(rowData.FLAG_STATUS == 1){
                    $('tr.ui-jqgrid-labels').addClass('ui-state-disabled ui-jqgrid-disablePointerEvents');
                }
            }
        }
```

How can I disable Header Check box `(multiselect = true)`, only when `ALL` rows are disabled i.e `hasClass(ui-state-disabled)` ?

jQgrid version = `4.6`
jQuery version = `1.7.2`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to save the information whether all row are disabled or not inside of your custom option of jqGrid. The corresponding code could be like on the demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/aagxejj5/44/ which uses

```
rowattr: function (item, rd, rowid) {
    var p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam");
    if (rd.closed === "true" || rd.closed === true) {
        return {"class": "ui-state-disabled ui-jqgrid-disablePointerEvents"};
    } else {
        p.isSomeEnabled = true;
    }
},
beforeRequest: function () {
    var p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam");
    p.isSomeEnabled = false; // reset for the filling
},
loadComplete: function () {
    var p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam"), $selAll = $("#cb_" + this.id);

    if (p.isSomeEnabled) {
        $selAll.removeClass("ui-state-disabled ui-jqgrid-disablePointerEvents");
        $selAll.click(); // select all
        // one need to trigger the click twice only because of bugs
        // in case of usage old jQuery version
        $selAll.click(); // select all
        $selAll.prop("checked", true);
    } else {
        $selAll.addClass("ui-state-disabled ui-jqgrid-disablePointerEvents");
        $selAll.prop("checked", false);
    }
}
```

I placed one enabled on the second page, so one can switch the pages and see that the above code correctly work.

Answer (score 0):

The checkbox in the header has the id which is combined from the "cb_" prefix and the grid id. So you can hide the element with

var myGrid = $("#list");
$("#cb_"+myGrid[0].id).hide();